# React | webpack | getting process.env.NODE_ENV== undefined on Azure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-devops, webpack-4

Used below scripts in package.json to set NODE_ENV while creating the build.

```
"scripts": {
    "build-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --config webpack.config.prod",
    "build-client": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.prod",
}
```

locally if I run **"npm run build-dev or build-client"** its working correctly and able to read correct NODE_ENV on webpack.config.common.js file.

But if I try same command to create build on Azure pipeline then **process.env.NODE_ENV returning as undefined**

Not sure on Azure why **"process.env.NODE_ENV"** returning as undefined.
Can someone please help to understand and what needs to be done on Azure to read correct NODE_ENV which was set at the Build time.

**Below are the pipeline details**

```
# Node.js
# Build Data Direct UI project with npm.
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger: none
#- master

pool: AGENTS

variables:
  system.debug : true
  
steps:

- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an Image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'CIS-DEV-001-SC'
    azureContainerRegistry: `{"loginServer":"acrncusd.azurecr.io", "id" : "acrncusd"}`



- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Push Image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'CIS-DEV-001-SC'
    azureContainerRegistry: `{"loginServer":"acrncusd.azurecr.io", "id" :  
    "acrncusd"}`
    action: 'Push an image'
    imageName: `$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)`
```

Comment: What's the result if you remove the whitespace before and after `&&`?

Comment: with removal of whitespace same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [windows-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software), we should remove the **whitespace** before and after the `&&`.

Try:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&&webpack --config webpack.config.prod",
    "build-client": "set NODE_ENV=production&&webpack --config webpack.config.prod",
}
```

Comment: Hi Lance, yes already tried adding and removing white space before and after && but on Azure pipeline build while reading process.env.NODE_ENV inside webpack.config.js file returning undefined. If I try to build it locally able to access correct process.env.NODE_ENV.

Comment: @sagar Which agent do you use, windows or linux, microsoft-hosted or self-hosted? Please consider adding the details about your build definitions and which step does the error comes from so that I can check for you directly.

Comment: Thanks Lance, we are using Linux agent and its self hosted. and what i am trying to do here at the build time based on the NODE_ENV read the .env file which contains the env detail info. Please let me know if need more info.

Comment: Could you share some details about your pipeline like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372045/azure-pipelines-encountered-errors-while-parsing-pipeline-yaml-unique-job-nam/63373858#63373858), I need some details to reproduce your issue. And what's the result if you use the pipeline using windows-latest agent, can the same task succeed?

Comment: As you requested below are the details: 
trigger: none 
variables:
  system.debug : true steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an Image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '001-SC'
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"acrsd.azurecr.io", "id" : "acrsd"}'
- task: Docker@0
displayName: 'Push Image'
inputs:
    azureSubscription: '001-SC'
    azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"acrsd.azurecr.io", "id" : "acrsd"}'
    action: 'Push an image'
    imageName: '$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)'

Comment: How does your dockerfile looks like? It seems this issue occurs in docker build step.

Comment: Actually its as per the format you mentioned in above comment "this thread", but in comment we can put max 550 chars, so pasted like above by removing white spaces.

Comment: @sagar It's recommended to add the details in question. You can see the `edit` button below your question, you can edit the question to add the details~

Comment: thanks for info. Updated pipeline details in question. Please let me know if need more info.

Comment: What's the result if you build the docker image locally like [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), I think maybe the issue is the built image itself.