# Azure Logic App, deployed using DevOps, first step "When a HTTP request is received", how to get the URL as output variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Long title: Azure Logic App, deployed using DevOps, first step "When a HTTP request is received", how to get the URL as output variable for use in deployment of App Service calling this Logic App?

My azure application is composed of two parts:

1. a Logic App
2. an App Service (web)
   which are both deployed using DevOps.

The first step of the logic app is "When a HTTP request is received".

The web has a dependency on the generated url
(e.g. https://prod-23.usgovarizona.logic.azure.us:443/workflows/.../triggers/request/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Frequest%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=...) of the logic app.

How do I get the URL of the logic apps' first step as an output variable,
so that I can supply that value in the deployment of the App Service,
which calls the Logic App?

I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-outputs?tabs=azure-powershell but that didn't help me.

release.json

```
{
"source": 2,
"revision": 59,
"description": null,
"lastRelease": {
    "id": 853,
    "name": "Release-37",
    "artifacts": [],
    "_links": {},
    "description": "Triggered by SMS Scheduler 2020.206.01.",
    "releaseDefinition": {
        "id": 14,
        "projectReference": null,
        "_links": {}
    },
},
"variables": {
    "depr_AppTeam": {
        "value": "SDIS"
    },
    "depr_DeptAbbr": {
        "value": "ENT"
    },
    "depr_ResourceGroupName": {
        "value": "$AppTeam+ \"-\"+ $AppName +\"-\"+$Env + \"-rg\""
    }
},
"variableGroups": [
    43
],
"environments": [
    {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "DEV",
        "rank": 1,
        "variables": {},
        "variableGroups": [],
        "deployStep": {
            "id": 90
        },
        "deployPhases": [
            {
                "deploymentInput": {
                    "parallelExecution": {
                        "parallelExecutionType": 0
                    },
                    "agentSpecification": {
                        "identifier": "vs2017-win2016"
                    },
                    "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
                    "artifactsDownloadInput": {
                        "downloadInputs": []
                    },
                    "queueId": 64,
                    "demands": [],
                    "enableAccessToken": false,
                    "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                    "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
                    "condition": "succeeded()",
                    "overrideInputs": {}
                },
                "rank": 1,
                "phaseType": 1,
                "name": "Agent job",
                "refName": null,
                "workflowTasks": [
                    {
                        "environment": {},
                        "taskId": "94a...",
                        "version": "2.*",
                        "name": "Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on $(AppTeam)-$(AppName)-$(Release.EnvironmentName)-rg",
                        "refName": "",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "alwaysRun": false,
                        "continueOnError": false,
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "definitionType": "task",
                        "overrideInputs": {},
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "inputs": {
                            "ConnectedServiceName": "nov...",
                            "action": "Create Or Update Resource Group",
                            "resourceGroupName": "$(AppTeam)-$(AppName)-$(Release.EnvironmentName)-rg",
                            "location": "USGov Arizona",
                            "templateLocation": "Linked artifact",
                            "csmFileLink": "",
                            "csmParametersFileLink": "",
                            "csmFile": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ent_sms_scheduler/Job1/template.json",
                            "csmParametersFile": "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ent_sms_scheduler/Job1/parameters.json",
                            "overrideParameters": "",
                            "deploymentMode": "Incremental",
                            "enableDeploymentPrerequisites": "None",
                            "deploymentGroupEndpoint": "",
                            "project": "",
                            "deploymentGroupName": "",
                            "copyAzureVMTags": "true",
                            "runAgentServiceAsUser": "false",
                            "userName": "",
                            "password": "",
                            "outputVariable": "",
                            "deploymentName": "",
                            "deploymentOutputs": "",
                            "addSpnToEnvironment": "false"
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
],
"triggers": [
    {
        "artifactAlias": "_ent_sms_scheduler",
        "triggerConditions": [],
        "triggerType": 1
    }
],
"releaseNameFormat": "Release-$(rev:r)",
"tags": [],
"properties": {
    "DefinitionCreationSource": {
        "$type": "System.String",
        "$value": "ReleaseNew"
    },
    "IntegrateJiraWorkItems": {
        "$type": "System.String",
        "$value": "false"
    },
    "IntegrateBoardsWorkItems": {
        "$type": "System.String",
        "$value": "False"
    }
},
"id": 14,
"name": "SMS SCHEDULER",
"path": "\\",
"projectReference": null,
"url": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/.../.../_apis/Release/definitions/14",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/.../.../_apis/Release/definitions/14"
    },
    "web": {
        "href": "https://dev.azure.com/.../.../_release?definitionId=14"
    }
}
```

}

release task:

```
steps:
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: 'Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group action on $(AppTeam)-$(AppName)-$(Release.EnvironmentName)-rg'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ENT-eComm-Deployment-NonProd-Gov-Connection'
    resourceGroupName: '$(AppTeam)-$(AppName)-$(Release.EnvironmentName)-rg'
    location: 'USGov Arizona'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ent_sms_scheduler/Job1/template.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ent_sms_scheduler/Job1/parameters.json'
```

Comment: Can you show part of pipeline related to Logic Apps?

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Hi Lance, Sorry. I have not been able to confirm this yet as I have some other blockers in my release pipeline.

Comment: That's ok, feel free to let me know when you get one chance to test my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you deploy Azure Logic App first, and then App Service.

You can add an [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) task after you deploy the Azure Logic app. Call [Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/get-azlogicapptriggercallbackurl?view=azps-4.7.0)
 command to get specific Logic App trigger callback URL. Example:

```
Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "LogicApp1" -TriggerName "manual"
Value                                                                                                                                                                                                               
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                               
https://prod-03.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/c4ed9335bc864140a11f4508d19acea3/triggers/manual/run?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=
```

And then you can define variables whose value is the response URL. Follow [use variables as inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-variables-as-task-inputs) and [detailed sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667924/cannot-set-powershell-output-variables-in-devops-step/62693182#62693182) to output this variable to following tasks.

Comment: Thanks Lance, I'll give that a try once my permissions are fixed. Right now I'm unable to edit/create releases. I'm also going to try the methods from these two posts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/WorkflowTriggers/ListCallbackUrl and https://mindbyte.nl/2019/02/13/Retrieve-the-callback-url-of-a-logic-app-inside-your-ARM-template.html

Comment: The first link is the Rest api way, it should also work for you when calling it via Azure Devops PS task. Both the `Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl`(Power command) and `Workflow Triggers` are officially recommended way :)